# Indexing large number of strings

Tags: indexing, redis, cassandra, bigdata

I have more than 2 million IDs, represented as 10-character strings each. These IDs correspond to documents that are going to be processed by multiple machines. What is the correct way to create a shared index that keeps track of the IDs that have been processed?

Is Cassandra the right tool to use or is it an overkill?

The frequent operations will be:

(1) Adding IDs to the index.

(2) Checking if an ID exists in the index.

Comment: Did you check the Redis Module https://redisearch.io?

Comment: My current implementation is based on redis, but I wanted to know if this is good practice or some other tool is preferable in this situation.

Comment: I guess it all depends on your latency requirements, if you need low latency Redis is your solution.

Comment: Also, the issue of single node crash, if you're using set/zset then all of your ids would be stored on the same machine, so if that machine crashes than potentially you could loose data.